# Change the start of a partition with parted?

Tags: partition, parted

How can I change the start location of a partition using parted or similar tool? It looks like you can only change the end location of partitions but that doesn't seem right.

https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#index-resizepart_002c-command-description

Comment: if you want to keep your data readable as before, then you'd have to move the data (perhaps hundreds of Go) when you'll move the start of the partition. that's why it's not offered or well hidden (I just don't know): dangerous

Comment: @A.B. I guess that makes sense. Assuming the data is sequential.

Comment: fdisk has this option in the expert menu. it will change the partition's start, *not* move the data. ie data considered to be lost if nothing else is done

Comment: Changing the start location of a partition *and keeping the data* is not a simple task. You need a specialized application for this purpose, for example [Gparted](https://gparted.org/). It is safer to backup the data, kill the partition, and create a new one.

Comment: It's not really that scary to move a resized partition, in many cases. But the best course of action does depend on many circumstances. Like @AlexP wrote, `Gparted` is an excellent tool to use for this purpose if you are in a graphic DE. Also `dd` may be very useful for imaging entire partitions or drives before you do something destructive.